# Algorithm for Hand writing recognition

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, pattern-recognition, handwriting

Is there any specific algorithm for handwriting recognition?
The algorithm should recognize the hand written letter.

Any one could help would be greatly appreciated in advance.

Thank you

Answer (score 23):

You can use a genetic algorithm:

http://www.foibg.com/ibs_isc/ibs-02/IBS-02-p03.pdf

You can use Greedy Point Match:

http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/msw/GreedyPointMatchWriteup.pdf

I would suggest reading this paper:

[On-Line and Off-Line Handwriting Recognition: A Comprehensive Survey](http://www.cedar.buffalo.edu/papers/articles/Online_Offline_2000.pdf)

Comment: Boosting was another easy, adaptive method for recognizing handwriting. check out adaboost, and its surrounding papers.

Answer (score 2):

[OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

There's the dollar family of recognizers which you can use to recognize single or multistroke gestures (and potentially map that to your alphabet) The lastest member of this family is the $P Recognizer. Here's a starting point: http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/pdollar.html

Answer (score 1):

Google has released an open source OCR engines [Tesseract OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/), and It has an [Python binding](http://code.google.com/p/pytesser/).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't do cursive / handwriting that I'm aware of ?

Answer (score 1):

This one seems to win all the major competitions lately: https://github.com/alexgraves/RNNLIB/wiki

Comment: Unfortunately that repository is currently empty.